# Use output from a command in another command

Tags: tox

I have a tox environment in which I want to run a bash command (basename) on {posargs} and use the result in a subsequent command.  I've tried the various ways it is possible to do this in bash, but they haven't been working.  This snippet captures the spirit of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
[testenv:docs]
commands =
    export PACKAGE=$(basename {posargs})
    ls $PACKAGE
```

Comment: Doesn't work with env vars: `tox` runs every command in a new shell so when the first command finishes the env var disappears. You have to save it somewhere in a permanent storage like a file. Or change approach completely like passing preprocessed `{posargs}` and use them in all commands down the pipeline.

Comment: Another thing I tried was ls $(basename {posagrs}) but that doesn't work either because tox doesn't really use a shell.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work as is. Simply because of what phd said above. The only one way is output through a file. However..

What you could do is:

> tox.ini

```
[testenv:docs]
passenv =
    PACKAGE
whitelist_externals =
    ls
commands =
    ls {env:PACKAGE}
```

> Inside whatever script runs tox..

```sh
export PACKAGE=$(basename {posargs})
tox
```

- This makes use of `tox`'s [variable substitution](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#environment-variable-substitutions).
- The `passenv` configuration option *alows* the PACKAGE environment variable to be passed (exist) into `tox`.
- The `whitelist_externals` sections enables commands (`ls`) not installed by `tox` (outside it's environment basically).